# Sending xml to Twilio in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twilio

I'm spiking on a rails app to make calls using twilio.  I'm using the twilio gem but when twilio hits my app to get the xml it blows up as there is nothing in the body of the response.  It calls my phone but says error in the app.

```
def index
  Twilio.connect('account sid', 'auth token')
  Twilio::Call.make('from number', 'to number', 'url')
end

def show
  @verb = Twilio::Verb.new { |v|
    v.say "The time is #{Time.now}"
    v.hangup
  }

  respond_to do |format|
    format.xml {render :xml => verb.response}
  end

end
```

And here is the error on twilio site.

Response: What your web application responded with to Twilio
HTTP Headers:
Key Value

X-Runtime   0.011953

X-Ua-Compatible IE=Edge,chrome=1

Transfer-Encoding   chunked

Date    Thu, 13 Oct 2011 16:13:21 GMT

Set-Cookie  _twilio_session=xxxxxxx; path=/; HttpOnly

Connection  close

X-Rack-Cache    invalidate, pass

Content-Type    text/html; charset=utf-8

Server  nginx/0.7.67

Cache-Control   no-cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added ".xml" to the end of the url in the Call.make and it worked.